# Change PHP include ("link.php") by click buttons

Tags: php, ajax

how to change PHP include ("link.html") by click buttons.

```
<?php include('link1.html')?>
BUTTON 1 change <?php include('link1.html')?> to <?php include('link2.html')?>
BUTTON 2 change <?php include('link1.html')?> to <?php include('link3.html')?>
BUTTON 3 change <?php include('link1.html')?> to <?php include('link4.html')?>
```

how to do this without refreshing page. using ajax?

Comment: Does link1.php contains HTML content? If you want to change the HTML content then define a div with unique ID and content may be change using ajax call.

Comment: yes, all the php files contains only HTML contents., EDIT: i change extension.

Comment: @RahulPatel let me try this.

Comment: Please try with the answers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Wrap `include('link1.html');` with a DIV with unique ID. And on click on button call a ajax and replace the DIV content.

Please try with below code.

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="DIVID">
    <?php
        include('link1.html');
    ?>
</div>
<button onclick="btnclick('link2.html')">Button 1</button>
<button onclick="btnclick('link3.html')">Button 2</button>
<button onclick="btnclick('link3.html')">Button 3</button>
<script type="text/javascript">
    function btnclick(_url){
        $.ajax({
            url : _url,
            type : 'post',
            success: function(data) {
             $('#DIVID').html(data);
            },
            error: function() {
             $('#DIVID').text('An error occurred');
            }
        });
    }
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do that with jquery, example:

**PHP Code:**

```
<div id="mainDiv"><?php include('link1.html')?></div>
<button onclick="change2()">Button 1</button><br />
<button onclick="change3()">Button 2</button><br />
<button onclick="change4()">Button 3</button><br />
```

**JQuery code**

```
function change2() {
  $('#mainDiv').load('link2.html');
}

function change3() {
  $('#mainDiv').load('link3.html');
}

function change4() {
  $('#mainDiv').load('link4.html');
}
```

Don't forget to include de JQuery

```
<script src="jquery/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>  
<button onclick="include( $( this ) )" value="2">Button 1</button>
<button onclick="include( $( this ) )" value="3">Button 2</button>
<button onclick="include( $( this ) )" value="4">Button 3</button>
<div id="included_page"><?php include('link1.html')?></div>

function include(elem)
{
  var page = elem.val();
  $.ajax({
    url: "link" + page + ".html",
    type: "GET"
  }).done(function(msg) {
    $('#included_page').html(msg);
    })
  })
}
```

I am not great at ajax but something along these lines may work, if you get any problems let us know.