# Prism.js Disturbs Ajax?

Tags: javascript, html, ajax, prism.js

I have two simple Python code files `hello.py` and `world.py`.

```
print("hello")
```

```
print("world")
```

Based on [this way](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39913138), I wrote, using both Prism.js and Ajax, an HTML file `helloworld.htm` that formats and presents either `hello.py` or `world.py` at a time as follows.

```
<!doctype html>
<script src=https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/prism/1.25.0/prism.min.js></script>
<script src=https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/prism/1.25.0/plugins/line-numbers/prism-line-numbers.min.js></script>
<script src=https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/prism/1.25.0/components/prism-python.min.js></script>
<link rel=stylesheet href=https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/prism/1.25.0/themes/prism.min.css>
<link rel=stylesheet href=https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/prism/1.25.0/plugins/line-numbers/prism-line-numbers.min.css>
<link rel=stylesheet href=https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/prism/1.25.0/themes/prism-coy.min.css>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    function btnclick(_url){
        $.ajax({
            url : _url,
            type : 'post',
            success: function(data) {
             $('#DIVID').html(data);
            },
            error: function() {
             $('#DIVID').text('An error occurred');
            }
        });
    }
</script>
<div style="width:50%;height:100%;position:fixed;top:0;left:0">
<a href="cursor:pointer" onclick="btnclick('hello.py')">hello.py</a><br>
<a href="cursor:pointer" onclick="btnclick('world.py')">world.py</a>
<div style="width:50%;height:100%;position:fixed;top:0;left:50%">
<pre class=line-numbers><code class=lang-py><div id="DIVID"><?php include('hello.py');?></div></code></pre>
```

Unfortunately, this HTML file does not work correctly with `<code class=lang-py>` in the last line. Though `<code>` instead of `<code class=lang-py>` solves this problem, I still want to use Prism.js to format the code files. How can I address this issue?

P.S. It seems that this problem is related to [How to Re-Run Prism.js on AJAX Content](https://schier.co/blog/how-to-re-run-prismjs-on-ajax-content) and that `Prism.highlightAll();` needs to be run together with Ajax, though I could not find the correct location of `Prism.highlightAll();` yet.